# Is stdin and console and keyboard input same

Tags: c, stdin

Is stdin and console and keyboard input same in C?

Answer (score 2):

From the [`isatty(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isatty.html) man page:

> The isatty() function tests whether fd is an open file descriptor referring to a terminal.

```
   #include <unistd.h>

   int isatty(int fd);
```

> isatty() returns 1 if fd is an open file descriptor referring to a terminal; otherwise 0 is returned, and errno is set to indicate the error.

So, `isatty(stdin)` will return nonzero if it is being typed, and zero if it's being redirected.

Comment: This means that stdin and console are not the same.

Comment: isatty() comes close, though a terminal isn't necessarily driven by a keyboard or user input, however the situations where it is driven programatically are ones where the program is expected to behave as if it's receiving keyboard input.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. You can essentially have a read() system call to accept input from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.  `stdin` can be redirected from a file (e.g. `executable < input`) or some other non-interactive device.

amphetamachine's answer gives you the tool to tell the difference.